# How do I turn x1, x2, y1, y2 array into rectangular vertices array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Say I have a two dimensional array of 4 columns, let's name the columns x1, x2, y1, y2, the data of the array are floats between 0 and 1, x2 is always larger than x1 and y2 is always larger than y1.

Each row represents a rectangle whose lower left corner is at (x1, y1) and whose width is x2-x1 and whose height is y2-y1.

The array is created like this:

```py
import numpy as np

bounds = np.random.uniform(size=(100, 4))
bounds[:,:2].sort(1)
bounds[:,2:].sort(1)
```

Now how do I create rectangular vertices from the array in this order: lower left, lower right, upper right, upper left, without using for loops?

I can do this:

```py
rectangles = [[(x1, y1), (x2, y1), (x2, y2), (x1, y2)] for x1, x2, y1, y2 in bounds]
```

But that defeats the purpose of using arrays in the first place.

Instead I can do these:

```py
lower_left = np.array((bounds[:, 0], bounds[:, 2])).T
lower_right = np.array((bounds[:, 1], bounds[:, 2])).T
upper_right = np.array((bounds[:, 1], bounds[:, 3])).T
upper_left = np.array((bounds[:, 0], bounds[:, 3])).T
```

Now I only need to figure out how to join the columns horizontally so that each row in the columns stays a sub row.

I have tried to do this:

`np.hstack((lower_left, lower_right, upper_right, upper_left))`

But it isn't exactly working as intended, the fields are joined, I need the points to stay separate for reasons that are irrelevant to the question.

How can I achieve exactly the same result as my list comprehension using vectorization?

---

### ***Edit***

I just figured out how to unpack array to columns:

`lower_left, lower_right, upper_right, upper_left = bounds.T`

Keep in mind I wrote all of these on an Android phone and I don't have physical access to actual computer on which I can do programming during nighttime (it is nighttime at my locale at time of writing), it is a complicated matter I won't discuss here.

The thing is I can't run complex code, for simple code using only built-in functions or standard library I can use w3c school's Python TryIt editor to run the code, but for anything requiring imports of any library installed via pip, I can't run the code, so I can't know for sure if my example will run.

---

### Edit

Fixed bug in example code, I wrote all of these on a phone so I can't run the code.

Comment: Looks like `np.array(rectangles)` will produce a (100,4,2) array.  Is that right?  What's `lr`?  Looks like (100,2).  You want to join 4 of these to make same shape?  I would use `np.stack((lr, ...), axis=1)`.  Or make all `lr` etc (100,1,2) shape, and do a simple concatenate on axis 1.  If you'd focused on shapes from the start the question would have gotten better votes.

Comment: Downvote is not only information for you but also information for other users. For me downvotes mean that question is boring and there is no need to visit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With fancy indexes, you can avoid unnecessary stacked arrays:

```
>>> rand = np.random.rand(10, 4)
>>> rand
array([[0.9975164 , 0.24502806, 0.39619553, 0.07442783],
       [0.57017416, 0.08316826, 0.16822264, 0.93233668],
       [0.62260765, 0.77285638, 0.30093986, 0.76024642],
       [0.26245902, 0.42329171, 0.31591031, 0.1685193 ],
       [0.55910866, 0.33132002, 0.37912662, 0.99307642],
       [0.02038662, 0.11176963, 0.72928163, 0.6766679 ],
       [0.59143993, 0.03891871, 0.80613796, 0.34442057],
       [0.47100568, 0.98703327, 0.60235766, 0.97791171],
       [0.63499569, 0.94171562, 0.06308767, 0.78651194],
       [0.679388  , 0.0464196 , 0.37712365, 0.76514397]])
>>> rand[:, :2].sort(1)
>>> rand[:, 2:].sort(1)
>>> rand[:, [0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 3]].reshape(-1, 4, 2)
array([[[0.24502806, 0.07442783],
        [0.9975164 , 0.07442783],
        [0.9975164 , 0.39619553],
        [0.24502806, 0.39619553]],

       [[0.08316826, 0.16822264],
        [0.57017416, 0.16822264],
        [0.57017416, 0.93233668],
        [0.08316826, 0.93233668]],

       [[0.62260765, 0.30093986],
        [0.77285638, 0.30093986],
        [0.77285638, 0.76024642],
        [0.62260765, 0.76024642]],

       [[0.26245902, 0.1685193 ],
        [0.42329171, 0.1685193 ],
        [0.42329171, 0.31591031],
        [0.26245902, 0.31591031]],

       [[0.33132002, 0.37912662],
        [0.55910866, 0.37912662],
        [0.55910866, 0.99307642],
        [0.33132002, 0.99307642]],

       [[0.02038662, 0.6766679 ],
        [0.11176963, 0.6766679 ],
        [0.11176963, 0.72928163],
        [0.02038662, 0.72928163]],

       [[0.03891871, 0.34442057],
        [0.59143993, 0.34442057],
        [0.59143993, 0.80613796],
        [0.03891871, 0.80613796]],

       [[0.47100568, 0.60235766],
        [0.98703327, 0.60235766],
        [0.98703327, 0.97791171],
        [0.47100568, 0.97791171]],

       [[0.63499569, 0.06308767],
        [0.94171562, 0.06308767],
        [0.94171562, 0.78651194],
        [0.63499569, 0.78651194]],

       [[0.0464196 , 0.37712365],
        [0.679388  , 0.37712365],
        [0.679388  , 0.76514397],
        [0.0464196 , 0.76514397]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already done it, I will post the code below just so that it may help anyone who stumbles here by Google searching:

```py
import numpy as np

values = np.random.random((100, 4))
values[:, :2].sort(1)
values[:, 2:].sort(1)
x1, x2, y1, y2 = values.T
ll = np.array((x1, y1)).T
lr = np.array((x2, y1)).T
ur = np.array((x2, y2)).T
ul = np.array((x1, y2)).T
rects = np.stack((ll, lr, ur, ul), axis=1)
rects.shape
```

It produces this:

`(100, 4, 2)`

Sample:

```
array([[[0.0296138 , 0.29131621],
        [0.3693961 , 0.29131621],
        [0.3693961 , 0.97544314],
        [0.0296138 , 0.97544314]],

       [[0.51630027, 0.39519657],
        [0.59897507, 0.39519657],
        [0.59897507, 0.76210139],
        [0.51630027, 0.76210139]],

       [[0.84594749, 0.42784315],
        [0.86691432, 0.42784315],
        [0.86691432, 0.79314211],
        [0.84594749, 0.79314211]],

       [[0.34412745, 0.21132195],
        [0.68466905, 0.21132195],
        [0.68466905, 0.25444418],
        [0.34412745, 0.25444418]],

       [[0.08766792, 0.39237762],
        [0.89154757, 0.39237762],
        [0.89154757, 0.44256892],
        [0.08766792, 0.44256892]],

       [[0.05022344, 0.54610173],
        [0.73931811, 0.54610173],
        [0.73931811, 0.96692603],
        [0.05022344, 0.96692603]],

       [[0.51423357, 0.48105812],
        [0.90815268, 0.48105812],
        [0.90815268, 0.93234461],
        [0.51423357, 0.93234461]],

       [[0.18887874, 0.28019687],
        [0.59905412, 0.28019687],
        [0.59905412, 0.61594758],
        [0.18887874, 0.61594758]],

       [[0.00589912, 0.50042431],
        [0.02952724, 0.50042431],
        [0.02952724, 0.93056696],
        [0.00589912, 0.93056696]],

       [[0.2267573 , 0.04920763],
        [0.43967406, 0.04920763],
        [0.43967406, 0.92892994],
        [0.2267573 , 0.92892994]],

       [[0.2885361 , 0.70178778],
        [0.73626986, 0.70178778],
        [0.73626986, 0.71951917],
        [0.2885361 , 0.71951917]],

       [[0.50806757, 0.2228232 ],
        [0.64801743, 0.2228232 ],
        [0.64801743, 0.58853764],
        [0.50806757, 0.58853764]],

       [[0.52227217, 0.08670711],
        [0.79866514, 0.08670711],
        [0.79866514, 0.95127646],
        [0.52227217, 0.95127646]],

       [[0.09714329, 0.38051135],
        [0.68042731, 0.38051135],
        [0.68042731, 0.6425565 ],
        [0.09714329, 0.6425565 ]],

       [[0.28889578, 0.83151436],
        [0.58681713, 0.83151436],
        [0.58681713, 0.94071716],
        [0.28889578, 0.94071716]],

       [[0.2109561 , 0.05147464],
        [0.52700784, 0.05147464],
        [0.52700784, 0.21706122],
        [0.2109561 , 0.21706122]]])
```